# A confusion about the integral $\int_{0}^{1} x^l e^{-\lambda(1-x)} dx$

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion

A basic calculation shows:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} x^l e^{-\lambda(1-x)} dx = \frac{l!}{(-\lambda)^{l+1}} \left( \sum\limits_{j=l+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-\lambda)^j}{j!}\right)
$$
where $\lambda$ is a constant.

I have:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} x^l e^{-\lambda(1-x)} dx = e^{-\lambda} \int_{0}^{1} x^l e^{\lambda x} dx = \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda^{l+1}} \int_{0}^{1} (\lambda x)^l e^{{\lambda x}}
d(\lambda x)
$$

$$
=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda^{l+1}} \left[ \left( \sum\limits_{j=0}^{l}(-1)^j \frac{l!}{(l-j)!} (\lambda x)^{l-j}
\right) e^{\lambda x}\right]_{0}^{1}
$$

I can't obtain the equation. Can someone give me some suggestion to prove it? Thank you.

Comment: Wait a minute, if it’s a definite integral being integrated with respect to $x$, shouldn’t the RHS be free of $x$?

Comment: sry, I didn't write my thoughts completely, which caused confusion for you. I have already edited it.

Comment: Index your last sum from backwards. Call $j=l-k$ with $k$ running between $0$ and $l$.

Answer (score 2):

My first instinct looking at the expression was to turn it into Gamma density, so that's what I did

$$\int_0^1x^le^{-\lambda{(1-x)}}dx=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\Gamma(l+1)}{(-\lambda)^{l+1}}\int_0^1\frac{1}{\Gamma(l+1)}(-\lambda)^{l+1}x^{(l+1)-1}e^{-(-\lambda) x}dx$$

Then I realized there isn't a closed form for the cdf. Thankfully, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Characterization_using_shape_%CE%B1_and_rate_%CE%B2) came to the rescue with the following:

> If $\alpha$ is a positive integer, then the cdf has the following series expansion
> $$F(x;\alpha,\beta) = 1-\sum_{i=0}^{\alpha-1} \frac{(\beta x)^i}{i!} e^{-\beta x} = e^{-\beta x} \sum_{i=\alpha}^{\infty} \frac{(\beta x)^i}{i!}$$

We plug in $x=1, \alpha=l+1, \beta=(-\lambda)$ to get

$$e^{-\lambda}\frac{\Gamma(l+1)}{(-\lambda)^{l+1}}e^{\lambda}\sum_{i=l+1}^{\infty}\frac{(-\lambda)^{i}}{i!}=\frac{l!}{(-\lambda)^{l+1}}\left( \sum_{i=l+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-\lambda)^i}{i!} \right)$$

Comment: thx u! this helps me a lot！